# How can I refactor my code to Javascript ES6 using map or filter?

Tags: javascript

This function takes an array of driver objects as the first argument and a JavaScript object that specifies an attribute and corresponding value. 
For example, `exactMatch(drivers, { revenue: 3000 })` will return all drivers whose revenue attribute equals 3000, and `exactMatch(drivers, { name: 'Bob' })` will return all drivers whose name attribute equals Bob.

I have tried setting it up with map and filter with no success. Im trying to rewrite this code using ES6 format with map or filter, or otherwise just refactor for better code. Any help would be appreciated! I am very new to programming and JS in general.

```
function exactMatch(drivers, obj){
  const driverMatch = [];
  for (const driver of drivers){
    for (const key in obj){
      if (driver[key] === obj[key]){
        driverMatch.push(driver);
      }
    }
  }
  return driverMatch;
}
```

Refactor for better code and to use JS ES6.

Comment: `map` and `filter` are not ES6 - they were available in ES5.

Comment: do you have only one key/value in `obj` or more and what should happen then? should all properties match or only one?

Comment: I should have been more specific - looking to use the arrow function with map or filter.

Comment: @AlisonGolden there is (almost) no difference between using `.map` and `.filter` with a normal function and using an arrow function. They are [interchangeable unless with some caveats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/are-arrow-functions-and-functions-equivalent-exchangeable). But you with this case, none of these should apply.

Comment: According to the lab tests its just one key/value pair in obj being passed in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer:

```js
function exactMatch(drivers, obj) {
  return drivers.filter(driver => {
    const truths = Object.keys(obj).map(k => driver[k] === obj[k])
    return truths.filter(Boolean).length === truths.length
  })
}
```

There are several ways you could do this, but this was the first way that came to me. This is assuming you could pass an obj like `{ name: 'Bob', salary: 20000 }` and require both of those conditions to be true.

Comment: This answer is exactly what I was looking for..simple and clean and it worked! Can you explain why the use of (Boolean)? Im a little confused by that.

Comment: Nevermind..I understand the Boolean being used to filter and return the match cases. I was also specifically looking for a solution on how to use Object.keys appropriately and this clearly defines it for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I would just generate a predicate from the second parameter. Since it contains a keys and a values, then [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) will de-compose it into those and you can generate a predicate from it that simply runs [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) on each key-value pair to check if an object matches each of those:

```js
const makePredicate = template => {
  const keyValues = Object.entries(template);
  
  return obj => keyValues.every(([key, value]) => obj[key] === value)
}

const predicate = makePredicate({name: "Bob"});

const a = {name: "Alice"};
const b = {name: "Bob"};

console.log(predicate(a));
console.log(predicate(b));
```

So you can use this predicate in `Array#filter` directly afterwards:

```js
const makePredicate = template => {
  const keyValues = Object.entries(template);

  return obj => keyValues.every(([key, value]) => obj[key] === value)
}
const drivers = [{
    name: "Alice",
    revenue: 20000,
    colour: "red"
  },
  {
    name: "Bob",
    revenue: 10000,
    colour: "blue"
  },
  {
    name: "Carol",
    revenue: 10000,
    colour: "red"
  }
]

console.log(drivers.filter(makePredicate({
  name: "Bob"
})));

console.log(drivers.filter(makePredicate({
  revenue: 10000,
  colour: "red"
})));
```

If you want to only match at least one of the key-values supplied, then you can swap and use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```js
const makePredicate = template => {
  const keyValues = Object.entries(template);

  return obj => keyValues.some(([key, value]) => obj[key] === value)
  //                      ^^^^
}
const drivers = [{
    name: "Alice",
    revenue: 20000,
    colour: "red"
  },
  {
    name: "Bob",
    revenue: 10000,
    colour: "blue"
  },
  {
    name: "Carol",
    revenue: 10000,
    colour: "red"
  }
]

console.log(drivers.filter(makePredicate({
  name: "Bob"
})));

console.log(drivers.filter(makePredicate({
  revenue: 10000,
  colour: "red"
})));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could get the entries of `obj` in advance and filter the array and check with [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), if one key/value pair match.

```
// one property match
function exactMatch(drivers, obj) {
    var entries = Object.entries(obj);
    return drivers.filter(driver => entries.some(([k, v]) => driver[k] === v));
}
```

For all properties who should match, you could take [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every).

```
// all properties have to match
function exactMatch(drivers, obj) {
    var entries = Object.entries(obj);
    return drivers.filter(driver => entries.every(([k, v]) => driver[k] === v));
}
```

Comment: I havent used Array#some or Array#every yet but I like this solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```js
const exampleData = {
  drivers: [
    {
      name: 'Bob',
      revenue: 5000,
    },
    {
      name: 'Alice',
      revenue: 3000
    },
    {
      name: 'Allen',
      revenue: 4000
    },
    {
      name: 'Monkey',
      revenue: 5000
    }
  ]
};

// Finds the first occurance
function exactMatch(exampleData, target) {
  const targetKey = Object.keys(target)[0]
  const targetValue = Object.values(target)[0]
  return exampleData.drivers.find(driver => driver[targetKey] === targetValue)
}

// Finds all of the data that met the condition

function matchAll(exampleData, target) {
  const targetKey = Object.keys(target)[0]
  const targetValue = Object.values(target)[0]
  return exampleData.drivers.filter(driver => driver[targetKey] === targetValue)
}

const resultA = exactMatch(exampleData, {revenue: 4000})
console.log(resultA)

const resultB = matchAll(exampleData, {revenue: 5000})
console.log(resultB)
```